# iOS UIKit controllers to present news feed with photos

Tags: ios, ios6, uikit, uitableview

I am a newbie to iOS and developing a social application for iPhone (build using iOS 6 SDK).

One of the main pages of my application is the vertically scrolled news feed, sorted by time, that should generally display status updates. Each status update presents the user name, a user thumbnail photo, some content text and most probably some photos or videos along with few buttons to like or share with expandable comments list.

The status updates content are all stored in a RESTtful remote server.

It made me some sense to implement it with UITableViewcontroller, that also offers refreshing for free:

1. How can I create a custom Subtitle style UITableViewCell with a large image/video below (something like with Facebook or Instagram)? are there any code examples for creating this customized cell?
2. If it should not be constructed using the UITableViewCell/UITableViewController, which other iOS UIKit controllers should be used in order to present this news feed?
3. There are probably some great ready to use open source frameworks for that - which would you recommend?

Thanks a bunch in advance,
Asaf

Comment: u can add new feeds to the current array and reload the table and for new feed you can use pull to refresh like functionality

Comment: Have you googled?  http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=custom+uitableviewcell+tutorial

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I wanted to know what is the right and best way to implement it, and if there are open source frameworks for that.

Comment: @asafam what do exactly u want to know..how to show image text on tableview or how to add new feeds on tableview

Comment: thank you @VivekSehrawat I refined my question

Comment: @asafam UITableView can fulfill all your requirments, no need to look for any framework or any other control. there are many tutorials on internet for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Their are many tutorials you can download source code and can read apple [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) of UITableView and here you can see the tutorial [Here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/customizing-uitableview-cell/)
.
Below is the code for basic showing the image,title and subtitle by default

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        NSString *CellIdentifier =@"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
        cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        cell.textLabel.text=[titleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text=[subtitle objectAtIndexPath.row];
    return cell;
    }
```

If u want to make a custom cell then, set frames according to your need and use SDWebImage library to cache the images

```
UserImageView =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,0,70, 70) ];
nameLbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(95, 20, 200, 20)];
[nameLbl setText:nameStr];
[UserImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:responseString] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
[cell.contentView addSubview:nameLbl];
[cell.contentView addSubview:UserImageView];
```